# How to return another value from WITH clause after Inserting

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I try to use With clauses to make insertion to another table. I can return the id from the final query but the main goal is to get name of the adapter.

```
With AdapterName as (Select CONCAT('s', LTRIM(name, 's')::integer+1) as new_name
                     From adapter
                     Where adapter.name LIKE 's%'
                     Order by id desc
                     Limit 1),
     AdapterIns as (INSERT INTO adapter (create_date,name,tag) SELECT now(),new_name, new_name From AdapterName RETURNING id,name)
INSERT INTO user_adapter (create_date, user_id, adapter_id)
Select now(), 1, AdapterIns.id
From AdapterIns
RETURNING adapter_id;
```

How can I return AdapterIns.name as a final result?

Thanks,

**Update**: I also tried joining the adapter_id with original table but getting following error for the latest INSERT:

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT"

```
Select adapter.name
From adapter
        Join (With AdapterName as (Select CONCAT('s', LTRIM(name, 's')::integer+1) as new_name
                                          From adapter
                                          Where adapter.name LIKE 's%'
                                          Order by id desc
                                          Limit 1),
                          AdapterIns as (INSERT INTO adapter (create_date,name,tag) SELECT now(),new_name, new_name From AdapterName RETURNING id)
                     INSERT INTO user_adapter (create_date, user_id, adapter_id)
                     Select now(), 1, AdapterIns.id
                     From AdapterIns
                         RETURNING adapter_id) temp on adapter.id = temp.adapter_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shaping the second insert statement as a CTE too (I call it `original_insert` below) and then selecting will help.

```sql
With AdapterName as (Select CONCAT('s', LTRIM(name, 's')::integer+1) as new_name
                     From adapter
                     Where adapter.name LIKE 's%'
                     Order by id desc
                     Limit 1),
      AdapterIns as (INSERT INTO adapter (create_date,name,tag) SELECT now(),new_name, new_name From AdapterName RETURNING id,name),
 original_insert as (
                     INSERT INTO user_adapter (create_date, user_id, adapter_id)
                     Select now(), 1, AdapterIns.id
                     From AdapterIns
                     RETURNING adapter_id
                    )
SELECT oi.adapter_id, ai.name 
FROM original_insert oi JOIN AdapterIns ai ON oi.adapter_id = ai.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Postgres only allows you to return the columns being inserted.

You can use `returning *` and then join back to the original table to get the name.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried it but SQL returns an error when a try joining back. I updated the original question to show what I tried with your solution